# SimpleDateFormat not working on 7.0 and above

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I'm working on an Application that supports multi-language (English and Spanish). I'm stuck with a simple date format conversation which is only failing on Android 7.0 and above when Locale = es.

This is strange because the same code is working absolutely fine on 6.0 and prior SDKs version. I also checked https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html
and it wasn't much of a help.

This is the code

```
    public String getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(Context context, String time)  {
    String output = "";/*Tue, 27 Aug 2013 18:10:00 Z*/
    SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        if (null != time) {
            Date date = new Date();
            date = utcFormat.parse(time); //Throws exception only on Espanol
            SimpleDateFormat format;
            if (is24HourFormat(context)) {
                format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
            }else {
                format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
            }
            output = format.format(date);
            String timeZoneName = TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(
                    TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date()),
                    TimeZone.SHORT);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(timeZoneName)) {
                output = output + " " + timeZoneName;
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
   // Unparseable date
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe the `String time` parameter has changed

Comment: Why don't you unit test this, change `getDateTimeInDeviceLocale` parameters to accept the following `getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(String time, boolean is24Hours, Locale locale)` that would be a lot easier to test and reproduce the error.

Comment: If the day of week and month are always in English (such as `Tue` and `Aug`) you must use `Locale.ENGLISH` instead of `getDefault()` when parsing

Answer (score -1):

I tested it and seems fine to me, check other areas of your application

```
@Test
public void testGetDatetimeInDeviceLocale_en() throws ParseException{
    Locale english = Locale.ENGLISH;
    SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'", english);
    String testableDate = utcFormat.format(new Date(0));
    // test 24 hours format
    assertEquals("Thu Jan 01, 1970 02:00 BST", getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(true, testableDate, english));
    // test AM PM format
    assertEquals("Thu Jan 01, 1970 02:00 AM BST", getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(false, testableDate, english));
}

@Test
public void testGetDatetimeInDeviceLocale_es() throws ParseException{
    Locale spanish = Locale.forLanguageTag("es");
    SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'", spanish);
    String testableDate = utcFormat.format(new Date(0));
    // test 24 hours format
    assertEquals("jue ene 01, 1970 02:00 BST", getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(true, testableDate, spanish));
    // test AM PM format
    assertEquals("jue ene 01, 1970 02:00 AM BST", getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(false, testableDate, spanish));
}
```

P.S. As I suggested in the comment above you should change your method signature to the following:

```
public String getDateTimeInDeviceLocale(boolean is24Hours, String time, Locale locale) throws ParseException
```

P.P.S I have removed your catch and let the exception to be thrown to get error feedback.

Comment: As noted in my question, it only fails on Android 7.0 and above and when selected language is other than en_US (in my case it's Spanish)

Comment: It has something to do with Locale